# Can't set cortana as default voice assistant

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3

I have a Samsung Galaxy S3. I recently downloaded Cortana for android. There are multiple articles showing how to set her over Google now as default voice assistant. None seem to apply to my phone.

Is it simply not possible, or am I just doing it wrong?

If it's not possible, which Samsung Galaxy series does it start at? S4, S5?

If it's possible, please provide details of how to go about it. Because simply holding down the home button does not give me the option.

Thanks,

Alex

Comment: What articles or what specific article you refer and what instructions did you follow?

Answer (score 0):

http://wccftech.com/how-to-select-manage-default-apps-in-android-marshmallow/

Go into Settings --> Apps --> "Cog wheel in upper right corner" --> Default Apps --> Assist & voice input --> Assist app --> Choose Cortana

Cortana will now open when you hold LONG on the Home button instead of Google App.